# How to add number format function in decimal results in views 3

Tags: views

I am displaying some float value in my view. How can I make them till two decimal places?

Is there a way to add number_format function in view results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite the field output and use PHP to adjust it to your needs.

EDIT: To be able to actually use PHP in your rewrite rules you need an additional module called [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I did same but it does not work. I tried to Rewrite results ->Rewrite the output of this field ->Text      <?php number_format([percentage_1], 2); ?> then tried without PHP cotes but it does not work in both cases. it treates php function as text. Am I missing anything.

Comment: You probably are missing the extra module to use PHP, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your help. I am using D7 and the module has no D7 release. :(

Comment: The successor module for D7 is called Views PHP (http://drupal.org/project/views_php). It's still in dev, though.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my version of Views (7.x-3.8), there is a built in option for rounding.  It appears on the field views settings for any float.
- click on "Content: XXX" in the fields section
- check the box "Round", description "If checked, the number will be rounded."
- enter the number of decimal places in the "Precision" box.

In the views export it comes up as "set_precision".